# Class Sizes and Ordering

Tags: set-theory

It is independent of ZFC that every proper class has the same "size". (See [Size Of Proper Classes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386849/size-of-proper-classes)). However, is it necessary that the proper class sizes must be linearly ordered if then are not the same size? Is it possible (i.e. consistent with ZFC) to have the proper classes with some (non-strict) partial ordered? Furthermore, must there always exists a 'minimal' proper class size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

Start with a model of $\sf ZFC$, and add, with an Easton product, to every regular cardinal $\kappa\times 2$ Cohen subsets, $A_\kappa$ and $B_\kappa$ are the $\kappa\times\{0\}$ and $\kappa\times\{1\}$ sets respectively. Then the class $\{A_\kappa,B_\kappa\mid\kappa\in\sf Reg\}$ cannot be linearly ordered. You can find the details [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110799/does-zfc-prove-the-universe-is-linearly-orderable).

Now we have a proper class which cannot be linearly ordered. In particular, it cannot be put with bijection with the class of ordinals. Therefore the two classes are incomparable.

As for minimal, the class of ordinals is always minimal. But the above shows it doesn't have to be a minimum.

Comment: Thanks so much! this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome!